# Python: List of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, dataset, analytics

Please, if I have a list of tuples, say:

list = [('James', 27, 2000), ('Aaron', 24, 1290), ('Max', 23, 2300), ('Ben', 27, 1900)]

1. How do I get all the names in ascending order?
2. How do I get a list that shows the tuples in ascending order of names?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sort a list of tuples, by default the first item in the tuple is taken as the key. Therefore:

```
list_ = [('James', 27, 2000), ('Aaron', 24, 1290), ('Max', 23, 2300), ('Ben', 27, 1900)]

for name, *_ in sorted(list_):
    print(name)
```

**Output:**

```
Aaron
Ben
James
Max
```

Or, if you want the tuples then:

```
for t in sorted(list_):
    print(t)
```

...which produces:

```
('Aaron', 24, 1290)
('Ben', 27, 1900)
('James', 27, 2000)
('Max', 23, 2300)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by ascending you mean alphabetical?
You can do it with `sorted`:

```
a = [('James', 27, 2000), ('Aaron', 24, 1290), ('Max', 23, 2300), ('Ben', 27, 1900)]
sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Output:

```
[('Aaron', 24, 1290),
 ('Ben', 27, 1900),
 ('James', 27, 2000),
 ('Max', 23, 2300)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [('James', 27, 2000), ('Aaron', 24, 1290), ('Max', 23, 2300), ('Ben', 27, 1900)]

print(sorted(lst))
```

Prints

```
[('Aaron', 24, 1290), ('Ben', 27, 1900), ('James', 27, 2000), ('Max', 23, 2300)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [('James', 27, 2000), ('Aaron', 24, 1290), ('Max', 23, 2300), ('Ben', 27, 1900)]
```

1. 

```
sorted_names = sorted([i[0] for i in list])
print(sorted_names)
```

Output:

```
['Aaron', 'Ben', 'James', 'Max']
```

2. 

```
sorted_by_name = sorted(list, key=lambda tup: tup[0])
print(sorted_by_name)
```

Output:

```
[('Aaron', 24, 1290), ('Ben', 27, 1900), ('James', 27, 2000), ('Max', 23, 2300)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [('James', 27, 2000), ('Aaron', 24, 1290), ('Max', 23, 2300), ('Ben', 27, 1900)]
>>> sorted([name for name, _, _ in l])
['Aaron', 'Ben', 'James', 'Max']
>>> sorted(l)
[('Aaron', 24, 1290), ('Ben', 27, 1900), ('James', 27, 2000), ('Max', 23, 2300)]
```

Be advised that `list` is an object in Python, so when you create a variable with the name `list`, you overwrite that reference and you cannot use `list(something)` after in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `key` parameter in `sort` or `sorted` function. Here's an example:

```py
my_list = [('James', 27, 2000), ('Aaron', 24, 1290), ('Max', 23, 2300), ('Ben', 27, 1900)]
my_list_sorted_by_names = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

And the result will be:

```
[('Aaron', 24, 1290), ('Ben', 27, 1900), ('James', 27, 2000), ('Max', 23, 2300)]
```

You can use list comprehension to extract names from sorted list:

```py
ordered_names = [i[0] for i in my_list_sorted_by_names]
```

Comment: In this case, because the sort is on the first item in the tuple, there's no need to specify a key